# What is a good HFS+ NAS or network HDD

Tags: nas, metadata, hfs+

I am wondering what would be a good, if any, NAS i can find with HFS+. My reason for wanting this is that I need the metainformation in the files to stay intact as I am dealing with a lot of OpenMeta tags.

For me this can be any NAS or "external HDD with network connection".

The question has been raised here ([Which NAS for Mac users?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47618/which-nas-for-mac-users)) previously, but was not answered as to what drives do have HFS+.

Comment: Avoid Synology (even with latest DSM). Recurring dropped connections while copying files, and performance suffers from repeated file system checks. Question posed in Synology Support forum was unanswered.

Comment: Wow. My thoughts are synology is the best around in terms of value, performance and support. I haven't been able to break one lately and most consumer NAS are easy to send into fits if you try.

Comment: I also was gonna suggest synology, and tell him to give up HFS+. LOL

Comment: Just what kind of metas do you need, most of them are in most file systems.

Comment: bmike, I bought Synology after hearing anecdotal recommendation from friends. Sadly, DSM 4.1 is problematic with 64-bit OS X 10.8.2 and Synology-approved D-Link dual-band 802.11n connecting to a WPA2PSK, TKIP, hidden SSID network

Comment: to the question on what kind of meta i need - as stated above: OpenMeta. http://code.google.com/p/openmeta/

Answer (score 1):

So, HFS+ is a closed, proprietary format. For linux to work with this format, it needs `hfsprogs`, which is a module that supports HFS+.

Most NAS servers use linux-native formats, so if you want HFS+-based filesystems, there are a few ways.

a) Most NAS servers are built with Linux, and most of them have command line. You can load `hfsprogs` module and write a script to have the system mount your HFS+ formatted drives. In another word, customize the system.

b) Roll your own server, a good Synology enclosure costs about the same price as an Mac mini, you can get an external hard drive and have it running as an server.

Comment: So, what we are saying here is that there exists no network HDD or NAS that are built with a HFS+ formatted drive? I find that hard to believe. I hope that there is a solution where I don't have to experiment with customizing a linux server. I'm happy that it is "possible" to hack ones way into it, but I'm in a situation now where I need to buy something that "just works". So, I am afraid this does not answer my question. Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: @gorgon I do understand. Will you give me some information about your needs and settings, maybe I can put together a solution for you. I am planning a storage solution for my school and myself recently.

Comment: @gorgon Also, how does OpenMeta function? How do you add meta data to a file? I haven't had a chance to read its instruction since I'm constructing a network recently. I think you should make sure that OpenMeta works IF a file is copied to another CLEAN machine like your new NAS server will be.

Answer (score 0):

Get any NAS, create and mount a NAS volume on your mac (I use afp with my Synology DS1511).  Then use disk utility to create and mount a disk image stored on the NAS which will be in HFS+ format by default.

Yes, it's an extra step but I think it will get you what you want, a mounted NAS hosted HFS+ volume.

Sidenote:  My Synology NAS is great but I have stayed with DSM 3.2, it works.  That and my NAS is not attached to the net at large.